# Return 64 bit integer from purrr::map_*

Tags: r, purrr, bit64

How do I return a 64-bit integer from purrr::map_*?

Below does not work

```
library(bit64)
library(tidyverse)

tibble(x=1:3) %>% 
  mutate(y=map_int(x,~{return(as.integer64(2^55))}))
```

> Error in `mutate()`:
> ! Problem while computing `y = map_int(...)`.
> Caused by error:
> ! Can't coerce element 1 from a double to a integer
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

If I use `map()` instead of `map_*()` then I get a list-column of integer64. From what I understand, tibble/dplyr supports columns of 64-bit integers, so it would be great to know how to return them from `map_*()`

Comment: just curious, why don't you just use `map()` followed by `%>% unnest(y)`?

Comment: @langtang, that is a great work-around, thank you. I didn't realize unnest worked like that. This solves my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably easiest here is to simply pipe to `unnest()`:

```
tibble(x=1:3) %>% 
  mutate(y=map(x,~as.integer64(2^4))) %>%
  unnest(y)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
      x       y
  <int> <int64>
1     1      16
2     2      16
3     3      16
```